# Algorithm to check if two arrays are equal

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Lets say i need to construct an algorithm that determines if two arrays containing only integers contains the same numbers. The order or number of each value doesn't matter.

For an example what im after:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 100, 120} { 1, 4, 100, 2, 120, 3} -> true
{ 2, 5, 8, -2, -2, 100, 102} { 2, 5, -2, 100, 102} -> false
```

What is a good and methodical way to approach this problem and writing it down into psuedo code?

Comment: Depends on the language. In Python, it'd be `set(a1) == set(a2)`. In a lower-level language, it'd be much longer.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? This is a trivial problem you can figure out yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each array, make a sorted version and remove duplicates. Then, you can just compare these versions.

Alternatively, on a higher level, you may convert arrays into sets (unordered collections of unique elements), and then compare these sets.

Comment: Converting the array into a set will not work in the case of duplicates.

Comment: @Nikunj Banka: Please elaborate. Do you have a specific conversion process in mind? Also, note that the question states "The order _or number_ of each value doesn't matter.".

Comment: Ok its fine if the number of each value doesn't matter, upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Note I'm assuming that the cardinalities of matching elements must be the same in both arrays to call them a match. Your example does not make clear what to do in that case. @Gassa's solution is good, but there is a more general way to look at this.  Convert each array to a multiset and then compare the multisets.  @Gassa's sorted arrays are serving as easily comparable multisets.  But others multiset representations are possible.  A hash mapping elements to counts is another.  Balanced trees are yet another.

In Python, you can use the hash of counts method like this:

```
def toCountHash(a):
  h = {}
  for x in a:
    if x in h:
      h[x] += 1
    else:
      h[x] = 1
  h

def arraysHaveSameElements(a, b):
  return toCountHash(a) == toCountHash(b)
```

A final optimization is to use one array to add elements to a single multiset and then use the other to remove them, returning "not equal" if removal fails or if the final result is not the emptyset.

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest one (python ish pseudo code), try to read and understand whats going on in the code

```
count = 0 # keep a counter
for i in array A: # loop through items in A
  for j in array B: # nested loop, for every items in A, check if it is in B
    if i == j:
      count = count + 1 # increment the counter by 1 if it is in B
if count == len(Array A): # check if the counter is the number of elements in A
  return true # if so, return true
return false # false, otherwise
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution for most purposes. First, it's O(n^2) in run time when it's easily possible to do this in O(n).  Second, it's incorrect if the input arrays can have duplicates.

Comment: @Gene Obviously OP don't care... He will have to learn that the hard way

Comment: @Gene as i said, its the most simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

```
   1) Check length for both, If not equal then return false & done i.e they are not equal

   2) Otherwise grab one the array in temp variable and loop thru it while removing current index value from the other array.

   3) Check if other array is empty. If yes then equal otherwise not equal
```

Make sure to use temp variables and copy your array, otherwise you may end up removing elements from the original array